# pylons mongoengine type object 'Section' has no attribute _data

Tags: python, mongodb, pylons, mongoengine

In the model I define :

`section.py`:

```
class Section(Document):
    section_name = StringField(required = True)
```

and, also in the model:

`admin_interface.py`:

```
class AdminInterface(DynamicDocument):
    registered_model = ListField()
```

then, in controller:

`__init__.py`:

```
from helloworld.model.section import Section
from helloworld.model.admin_interface import AdminInterface

model = [
    Section
]

instance = AdminInterface(registered_model = model)
instance.save()
```

I got an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Section' has no attribute '_data'
```

is there anyway to fix this? I really don't know what to do. I want to save Section object, so later I can display it using `AdminInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate the model with an `Section` instance or append a `Section` instance later in your code.  You can't just provide a class as its non saveable.